# Error when trying to connect flutter app to web socket

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, socket.io

im trying to connect my flutter app with websocket, i guess server side is working fine but getting error below in client side, any idea why ? And also read similar questions, usually they say 'it's about device connection' but i can work with restful api's in my emulator so i think that's not the issue.

**Error**

```
 WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket
```

**Client Side**

```
 import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:live_chat_mongo/function.dart';
    import 'package:live_chat_mongo/models/Message.dart';
    import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;
    
    import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart';
    
    // STEP1:  Stream setup
    class StreamSocket {
      final _socketResponse = StreamController<String>();
    
      void Function(String) get addResponse => _socketResponse.sink.add;
    
      Stream<String> get getResponse => _socketResponse.stream;
    
      void dispose() {
        _socketResponse.close();
      }
    }
    
    StreamSocket streamSocket = StreamSocket();
    
    //STEP2: Add this function in main function in main.dart file and add incoming data to the stream
    void connectAndListen() {
      IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://localhost:8080/v1',
          OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());
      socket.onConnectError((data) => print(data));
      socket.onConnect((_) {
        print('connect');
      });
    
      //When an event recieved from server, data is added to the stream
      socket.on('event', (data) => streamSocket.addResponse);
      socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));
    }
    
    //Step3: Build widgets with streambuilder
    
    class BuildWithSocketStream extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: streamSocket.getResponse,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              return Container(
                child: Text('ds'),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    void main() {
      connectAndListen();
      runApp(MaterialApp(home: BuildWithSocketStream()));
    }
```

**Server Side**

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });

require("./app/services/mongo");
// require('./app/services/redis');

require("./app/models/User.js");
require("./app/models/Event.js");
require("./app/models/Committee.js");
require("./app/models/Comment.js");
require("./app/models/EventSession.js");
require("./app/models/Subscription.js");
require("./app/models/Form.js");
require("./app/models/Application.js");
require("./app/models/Announcement.js");
require("./app/models/MailToken.js");
require("./app/models/MailError.js");
require("./app/models/BlogPost.js");
require("./app/models/BlogComment.js");
require("./app/models/BlogCategory.js");

const app = require("./app");
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
io.on("connection", (s) => {
  console.log("socket.io connection");

});
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 7070);
const server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → localhost:${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: There's missing colon between hostname and port in `http://localhost8080/v1` --> `http://localhost:8080/v1`

Comment: Thanks a lot!, but it leaded to another error  WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket any idea about this?

Comment: From command line try this `curl "http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"` it should return something like `0{"sid":"Lbo5JLzTotvW3g2LAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000}
`

Comment: nope its <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /v1/socket.io/</pre>
</body>
</html>

Comment: also server prints GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket 404 0.528 ms - 149 constantly

Comment: What's with the `/v1`? Is your app actually available at /v1? What do you get with `curl "http://localhost:8080/v1/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"`? Just try both with and without /v1.

Comment: tried both already, the same result unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am facing this problem and I solved this issue by changing my version of socket_io_client

[image: here is the version that I changed check it out]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. changed Server Side to this;

   ```
        require("./app/services/mongo");
        // require('./app/services/redis');

        require("./app/models/User.js");
        require("./app/models/Event.js");
        require("./app/models/Committee.js");
        require("./app/models/Comment.js");
        require("./app/models/EventSession.js");
        require("./app/models/Subscription.js");
        require("./app/models/Form.js");
        require("./app/models/Application.js");
        require("./app/models/Announcement.js");
        require("./app/models/MailToken.js");
        require("./app/models/MailError.js");
        require("./app/models/BlogPost.js");
        require("./app/models/BlogComment.js");
        require("./app/models/BlogCategory.js");
        const socketIO = require("socket.io");
        const app = require("./app");
        const server = require("http").createServer(app);
        const io = socketIO(server);
        io.on("connection", (s) => {
          console.log("socket.io connection");
        });
        app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 7070);
        server.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
          console.log(`Express running → localhost:${server.address().port}`);
        });
   ```
2. Upgraded socket.io version in flutter to

   socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.2

And my problem fixed.